# How i can change the columns in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

For example if my columns view is for large screen

------1-(col-lg-4)---------|--------2-(col-lg-4)-------|----3-(col-lg-4)--------

I need to change the view of the column in bootstrap as per my order.
How i can change using the col function?

---------1(col-md-6)-----------|----------3(col-md-6)----------

--------------------2(col-md-12)--------------------

Comment: Like this [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/9cQSNRMDKElW8rHE0Bds)?

Comment: i have seen your code as per my requirements red must be 50% and green must be 50% in a row  and  blue should be 100% in a row.

Comment: and you should not swap the colors.it needs to be in the same order                          when in large screen  | col-lg-4 (red)|col-lg-4 (blue)|col-lg-4 (green)                                     when in small and medium screen | col-md-6(red)|col-md-6(green)| it should be in one row and               |              col- md-12( blue)        |

Comment: Have you personally tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a warning: Bootstrap isn't the most robust for moving content around responsively.  If you can drop old browser support, you will have more reliable support from [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"> <span>col 1</span> </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-push-4 col-sm-6"> <span>col 3</span> </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-pull-4 col-sm-12"> <span>col 2</span> </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the code is in a different order in the doc but it results in the order you mapped above:

https://jsfiddle.net/4jmzm9wm/

Answer (score 2):

You can use col-sm-12 and col-xs-12 for your small view in HTML. Like-

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 xol-xs-12">
<div>
```

If you do not specify any class for sm and xs. Bydefault, it will take 100% width i.e col-sm-12 itself.

If you want to divide the thing at one row for large screen for logo, search box, notification icons-

Try this-

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="float:left">Logo </div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">Search box</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="float:right">Notification icons</div>
<div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: for example : if i divide a column into three 1. i have a logo 2.search box 3.notification icons in large view  all the column  should to be in a single row.                                                                                                           but when i reduce the size of the window to tab and mobile    logo should be on left side and notification icon should be on the right side        and the search bar must be on the next row

Comment: I have edited my code. try this and use width/class as per your need :)

Comment: can any one provide me a answer